# Include library files in c#

Tags: c#, dll

How can I include library files into a c# project like c/c++, which uses #include<> to include  library files. As by 'using lib;' it is showing error.
kindly help

Comment: He's tried `using lib;`. "What have you tried" doesn't apply here. OP - downvote for not doing some basic google'ing. Sorry.

Comment: i have tried "using my_lib_name".

Comment: _"it is showing error"_ - always include full error info in the question. And exactly what you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add reference of library files which you want to add into your project by right clicking the project under solution explorer and then "add reference" and then browse or select from the list of dlls.

Answer (score 0):

you can add referense on library. Find References in your project, right click->Add Reference